# Dynamic self-referencing "upload_to" folder on ImageField

Tags: python, django

I have a model such as this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    red = models.ForeignKey(Anothermodel)
    blue = models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
```

Would it be possible for 'folder' to be set to the value of field 'red'?

My purpose is that when a user uploads an image, it is automatically stored on a folder that has some field from that very same model as its name.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `upload_to` also takes a callable (e.g. a function):

```
def blue_upload_to(instance, filename):
    folder = instance.red.some_field
    return folder + os.sep + filename

class MyModel(models.Model):
    red = models.ForeignKey(Anothermodel)
    blue = models.ImageField(upload_to=blue_upload_to)
```

The documentation provides some additional examples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: For those coming here long after, like I did, above link doesn't work. So here is a working one, with the same example:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield